# Extend BTRFS LUKS partition

Tags: btrfs, luks

A few years ago I used this excellent guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=co5V2YmFVEE to encrypt my Thinkpad disk with LUKS and use BTRFS as my file system.

My SSD at that time only had 256GB, now I have updated to 1TB and have used Clonezilla to clone my drive to the new SSD. The only question remains - how can I safely extend my LUKS encrypted partition and the BTRFS system (with 2 subvolumes - root and home) under it?

My /etc/fstab

```
# /dev/nvme0n1p1
UUID=6E39-1234          /boot       vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2

# /dev/mapper/cryptroot
UUID=d7cf34c3-8fb4-4cbb-b04b-96e8121e11d9   /           btrfs       rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=256,subvol=/@  0 0

# /dev/mapper/cryptroot
UUID=d7cf34c3-8fb4-4cbb-b04b-96e8121e11d9   /home       btrfs       rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=257,subvol=/@home  0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer my own question, this is the easiest way to do this (confirmed working - of course always have a backup ready, I had mine on my NAS via Clonezilla):

The name of my device is - **cryptroot**

1. Boot up a Live CD/USB (I use Arch so I picked that)
2. Open the encrypted partition - **cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p2 cryptroot**
3. Open the disk with parted, in my case /dev/nvme0n1 - **parted /dev/nvme0n1**
4. Print the partitions and then execute **resizepart NUMBER 100%** (where NUMBER is the ID of the encrypted partition - which should be last on disk, in my case 2)
5. Close the LUKS device once - **cryptsetup close cryptroot**
6. Opne the LUKS device again - **cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p2 cryptroot**
7. Resize LUKS - **cryptsetup resize cryptroot**
8. Mount the partition to any folder (I chose /partition) - **mount /dev/mapper/cryptroot /partition**
9. Resize BTRFS - **btrfs filesystem resize max /partition**
10. Unmount the partition
11. Close the LUKS device - **cryptsetup close cryptroot**
12. Restart into your OS

You can also do a test run on any Type 1 Hypervisor you use (that's what I did) - just restore the image via Clonezilla

Answer (score 0):

> how can I safely extend my LUKS encrypted partition

You can't. Yes you can resize the LUKS partition by creating a new PV and adding it but then resizing the BTRFS but it is **very** risky. There is no "safe" here. Create a new Partition in the empty space, use LUKS to provision it if you must, then migrate stuff from your existing partition.